# How to create DynamoDb table with a version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

`There are two versions of DynamoDB global tables available: Version 2019.11.21 (Current) and Version 2017.11.29.`
I can find out version of an already created table, but if I want to use specific version while creating the table, how can I do that?
I have cloudformation creating two tables one without global table other with global table.
Without global table is always created with 19 version, where as with global table is created with 17 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I want to use specific version while creating the table, how can I do that?

You **can't do this**. This is not something you can control explicitly at the table creation. If you have old version you can update to new vesion  **only in AWS console**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/V2globaltables_upgrade.html):

> Updating to version 2019.11.21 (current) is **only available through the DynamoDB console**.

To create 2017 version you have to use [create-global-table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/create-global-table.html) API call which is **not supported** in CloudFormation.

What's more the global table support in CloudFormation is still on **the development roadmap**:

- [AWS::DynamoDB::Table Global Tables](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/57)

Thus the only option is to develop [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) if you want to create and manage your global tables in CloudFormation.

Comment: I want to create DDb table with a global table in ca-central-1. I am creating global table using custom resource. While creating the table through CFN it complains that 
```DynamoDB global tables version 2017.11.29 is not supported in this region 'ca-central-1'```
I am wondering if there is a way to create global table in this region by using CFN (even with custom resource)

Comment: @noobCoder I would suggest creating new question with the relevant details and error messages.